# JUnit report generation for individual testcase

Tags: java, maven, reporting-services, junit, rest-assured

I am making an framework that internally user JUnit and REST Assured. This framework will have the 4 @Test methods for CRUD operations. Whenever the user want to do any operation, he will call only that particular Test method. But at the end of the each operation(say GET or DELETE or any other), it should generate the report.
I tried using [surefire-report](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html) plugin. As I have read, that will generate report only when we **build** the project(running all the Test methods).
 
Is there any mechanism that fulfills my requirement of generation report for individual run also?
Execution will be like : final output will be the jar with individual CRUD facility.
API.execute(GET, end_point_name);
API.execute(POST, end_point_name,data);
Test method get and post is called respectively for the above calls. Report should be generated for both the test cases for normal run as java application.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 solutions to your problem :

1. Either you write your logger statement and do proper logging of the events. You can either store it in DEBUG, INFO etc mode for better understanding and more control.
2. ExtentReports is another way to go : 
   http://www.ontestautomation.com/creating-html-reports-for-your-selenium-tests-using-extentreports/ refer the above link where they have a provided a detailed way of using the same.
3. You can also create a separate testng.xml file. Like maintaining a separate suite file this will internally make sure with the help surefire to create a separate reports.